# How to reduce headless Chromedriver startup time

Tags: python, selenium

I've just installed Selenium through pip and trying to load it up but it's taking like 20 seconds to load.

```
start = datetime.datetime.now()

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')

finish = datetime.datetime.now()
print("Startup time: " + str(finish - start))
```

here's the code I have right now and I'm getting back "Startup time: 0:00:22.632402".
is there some settings I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I run the same code. and Printed out the time interval .... Kill all chrome process and start again and do not forget to use .quit() method ... not to overflow process in background

Comment: I turns out it's a proxy issue. Once I disconnected from my VPN I was getting 1 second startup times. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Even with proxy it should not take such a long time .... I always have a long list of proxies ... for load the chrome but for loading a specific address or url the webpage loading time your comment can be a reason

Comment: Your Ram has been freed !